# How to Drag if in app have Both Drag-able Elements?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, draggable

I am new in selenium (Java). while doing practice i found this page where both elements are drag-able. i tried almost all the way...
http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/drag_and_drop

```
// ****Case 1****

    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    builder.dragAndDrop(fromWebElement, toWebElement);

// ****Case 2****

    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    Action dragAndDrop =
      builder.clickAndHold(fromWebElement).moveToElement(toWebElement)
        .release(toWebElement).build();
    dragAndDrop.perform();

// ****Case 3****
 Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    Action dragAndDrop =
      builder.clickAndHold(fromWebElement).moveToElement(toWebElement, 2, 2)
        .release(toWebElement).build();
    dragAndDrop.perform();


 //****Case 4****
    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    builder.clickAndHold(fromWebElement).moveToElement(toWebElement).perform();
    Thread.sleep(2000);// add 2 sec wait
    builder.release(toWebElement).build().perform();


 //****Case 5****
    Point coordinates1 = fromWebElement.getLocation();
    Point coordinates2 = toWebElement.getLocation();
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        robot.mouseMove(coordinates1.getX(), coordinates1.getY());
        robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
        robot.mouseMove(coordinates2.getX(), coordinates2.getY());
        robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
        Thread.sleep(2000);
```

Comment: still not able to handle it,,,,,

Answer (score 0):

try the below code:

```
@Test
public void test() throws InterruptedException, AWTException{

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();    

    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/drag_and_drop");
    Thread.sleep(3000);

    WebElement fromWebElement = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#column-a"));
    WebElement toWebElement = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#column-b"));

    int x = toWebElement.getLocation().getX();
    int y = toWebElement.getLocation().getY();

    Point coordinates = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#column-a")).getLocation();

     Robot robot = new Robot();
     robot.mouseMove(coordinates.getX()+120,coordinates.getY()+120);
     Thread.sleep(1000);

    Actions builder1 = new Actions(driver);
    builder1.clickAndHold(fromWebElement).moveToElement(toWebElement).release().build().perform();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    Point coordinates1 = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#column-b")).getLocation();
    Robot robot1 = new Robot();
    robot1.mouseMove(coordinates1.getX()+120,coordinates1.getY()+120);


    Thread.sleep(1000);
    Robot bot = new Robot();
    bot.mouseMove(x +120, y+120);    
    bot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    bot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
}
```

hope this will help you.

Comment: there is no error, and object in not even moving to 2nd object place (means A is not dragging to B side)

Comment: i give my full test case in updated answer...run this ..... if no success, than sorry as it works fine in my machine